# WCF net.pipe aborts when receiving response

Tags: wcf, named-pipes, known-types

**This has been resolved**

---

This is a contract I'm unable to get from a service call:

```
[DataContract]
public class myInitializationData : ClientInitializationData
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, string> CultureNameLookup { get; set; }
}
```

Here's it's base type,

```
[DataContract]
public class ClientInitializationData
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<IServiceType> ServiceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

`IServiceType` is an interface.  I realize I cannot send an interface across the wire.  There is an EntityFramework entity, `ServiceType`, implementing the `IServiceType` interface:

```
public partial class ServiceType : IServiceType
{
    //...
}
```

My goal is to send `ServiceType` entities across the wire via the `myInitializationData` contract.

I am prevented from decorating the `myInitializationData` or `ClientInitializationData` classes with a KnownType of `ServiceType`, because these classes are shared (linked) to Silverlight project(s).  So if I decorate either of these classes with a KnownType of `ServiceType`, the Silverlight side(s) will fail to compile.

Instead of decorating the classes directly, I decorated the service contract with with a ServiceKnownType of `ServiceType`:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ServiceType))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    myInitializationData InitializeClient();
}
```

Should this work?

When calling `IService.InitializeClient`, I receive the following error on the client:

```
There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).
```

I have enabled trace debugging but found no messages regarding failure to serialize in the trace for either client or server.

Server trace:

- Receives a message ever a channel
  (*Action: http://tempuri.org/IService/InitializeClient*)
- To: Execute
  (*IService.InitializeClient*)
- From: Execute
  (*IService.InitializeClient*)
- Sends a message over a channel
  (*Action: http://tempuri.org/IService/InitializeClientResponse*)
- Warning
  Faulted System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel
- Warning
  Faulted System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel
- Replying to an operation threw an exception
  (*The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*)

Client trace:

- Sends a message over a channel
  (*Action: http://tempuri.org/IService/InitializeClient*)
- Throwing an Exception
  (*There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).*)

If I opt the `ServiceTypes` property out of the `ClientInitializationData` DataContract, this error goes away.  So I assume this must be a serialization issue re: the interface and KnownTypes, but WCF isn't claiming to have any serialization issues in the trace, and I'm not sure what the trace means in this case.

---

**Solution**

This was not a KnownTypes issue.  It was the result of LazyLoading having been spontaneously enabled on the entity context defining the `ServiceType` type.

Although there is no mention of excessive message or a buffer sizes being violated in the trace (on either the client or server sides),  I must assume the enabling of LazyLoading on the EF context caused the DataContractSerializer to trigger EF into fetching **a lot** of records, which in turn resulted in a massive graph being (attempted) on the wire.  The server side was simply (and ambiguously) faulting the channel during the message write.

Returning LazyLoading to a disabled state on the EF context has since solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a KnownTypes issue. It was the result of LazyLoading having been spontaneously enabled on the entity context defining the ServiceType type.

Although there is no mention of excessive message or a buffer sizes being violated in the trace (on either the client or server sides), I must assume the enabling of LazyLoading on the EF context caused the DataContractSerializer to trigger EF into fetching a lot of records, which in turn resulted in a massive graph being (attempted) on the wire. The server side was simply (and ambiguously) faulting the channel during the message write.

Returning LazyLoading to a disabled state on the EF context has since solved this problem.